# Google Sheet Formula to Look for Specific Value and Copy The Data On the Right

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet that has two tabs

- DATA
- LOADER

I'm looking for an array formula that will be placed on LOADER that will look for a specific string of data in DATA, display it and finally split it.

This is how the data looks like on DATA tab
https://i.imgur.com/gBSLgNb.png

This is the expected result with the formula.
https://i.imgur.com/VveaehC.png

Here's the sample Google Sheet:

- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iEgKui7oOjGun7UZdNH-SeFb4PKQWinvhCG-8wfL9n8/edit#gid=154342848

I tried several formulas such as

- =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("coverage_1",DATA!$B$2:$D)),SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(DATA!$B$2:$D,"coverage_1,(.*)"),","),""))
- =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(DATA!$B$2:$D, "coverage_1"), SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(DATA!$B$2:$D, "coverage_1,", ""), ","), ""))

But none didn't work as intended.

Comment: Please share the sample sheet with us.

Comment: You said `copy it`. Formulas  are dynamic; they display results of a calculation but they do NOT permanently "copy" those results into given cells. "Copy" requires a script. Do you want to display the results of a formula, or (permanently) copy the results into the spreadsheet?

Comment: Hello, I edited the post and added the Google Sheet link.

@Harun24hr

Comment: @Tedinoz My apologies, I want the formula to display the result on the "loader" tab of the Sheet. I added the Google Sheet link for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's *one approach* based on your test data:

```
=let(col1_,scan(,index(column(B1:P1)^0),lambda(a,c,if(a+c>3,1,a+c))), col2_,index(left(B1:P1,10)),Σ,byrow(DATA!B2:D,lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,textjoin(char(10),1,Σ)))),
    makearray(counta(A2:A),counta(col2_),lambda(r,c,iferror(index(split(regexextract(index(Σ,r),index(col2_,,c)&".*"),","),index(col1_,,c))))))
```

[image]

Comment: This is almost perfect. Thank you! :)

However, when I try to expand it. For example, coverage_11, coverage_12, ... coverage_35.

The values that appear on coverage_11, coverage_12 etc. under the coverage_1X series. It will have coverage_1 result.

Comment: Do recreate this error scenario in the test sheet & I can check it out.

Comment: Please see the sample here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iEgKui7oOjGun7UZdNH-SeFb4PKQWinvhCG-8wfL9n8/edit#gid=154342848

Comment: replace this part of the formula `left(B1:P1,10)` with `regexextract(B1:V1,".*\d+")`